# How to find native ASIO drivers?

Tags: audio-interfaces, asio

I have an HP Pavilion g7 laptop that comes with an AMD sound card (IDT HD Audio Codec etc.), but must use an ASIO driver with my Native Instruments Maschine. ASIO4ALL is pretty terrible, so how would I find and use the native ASIO driver that comes with my sound card (if there is one)?

Comment: I had great success with asio4all on a desktop w/Realtek audio. (with both NI guitar rig and Reaper DAW). I had the lowest latency when I locked the "card" to 96k. Can you elaborate on your troubles?

Comment: @horatio The audio quality with ASIO4ALL is pretty bad, and I can't use any other applications with it. I have to switch the driver on and off to use other programs with sound.

Comment: ASIO requires exclusive hardware access unfortunately, so you are stuck with that. As far as quality: analog noise (i.e. electronic interferance), skipping and locking (buffers too low; disable forced sampling rate conversion;); other?

Answer (score 1):

Integrated sound cards generally do not have ASIO drivers. However, if yours does then your most likely to find it through the HP website in their drivers section. Or perhaps look at the drivers section from the sound card manufacturers website.

Answer (score 1):

It is, from personal experience, pretty uncommon for builtin/integrated sound hardware to include drivers with ASIO support. If they do exist, you'll find them on the manufacturer's website if they aren't already included with the hardware. If they don't, you're stuck with ASIO4ALL (which itself is kind of a workaround) unless you invest in some audio interface that does include ASIO drivers.